# Suffix option for SpinBox on Qt Quick Controls 2

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols2

With Qt Quick Controls, one can specify a suffix in the spinbox (the units of your number), just editing the property "[suffix](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-spinbox.html#suffix-prop)".

I was wondering whether this is possible with Qt Quick Controls 2.0, where this property is not available. Any suggestion how to do that by [customizing the spinbox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox) without too much effort?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet implemented: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51022 (feel free to vote or comment to help us prioritize)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE - EASY WAY**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

SpinBox{
    width: 180
    height: 40
    from: 1
    to: 12
    textFromValue: function(value, locale) {
                            return (value === 1 ? qsTr("%1 hour")
                                                : qsTr("%1 hours")).arg(value);
                   }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I have created my own Custom SpinBox.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

SpinBox {
    id: control
    property int buttonWidth: 40
    property int buttonHeight: 40
    property string baseColor: "#007194"
    property string suffix: ""

    value: 50
    editable: true

    contentItem: RowLayout{
        z: 2
        TextInput {
            id: txtInput
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: control.textFromValue(control.value, control.locale)
            font: control.font
            color: Qt.darker(baseColor, control.enabled ? 1 : 0.7)
            selectionColor: baseColor
            selectedTextColor: "#ffffff"
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

            readOnly: !control.editable
            validator: control.validator
            inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
        }
        Text{
            Layout.preferredWidth: contentWidth
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            z: -1
            font: txtInput.font
            color: txtInput.color
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            text: suffix
        }
    }

    up.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? 0 : parent.width - width
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: buttonWidth
        implicitHeight: buttonHeight
        color: up.pressed ? "#e4e4e4" : "#f6f6f6"
        border.color: enabled ? baseColor : "#bdbebf"

        Text {
            text: "+"
            font.pixelSize: control.font.pixelSize * 2
            color: Qt.darker(baseColor, control.enabled ? 1 : 0.7)
            anchors.fill: parent
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

    down.indicator: Rectangle {
        x: control.mirrored ? parent.width - width : 0
        height: parent.height
        implicitWidth: buttonWidth
        implicitHeight: buttonHeight
        color: down.pressed ? "#e4e4e4" : "#f6f6f6"
        border.color: enabled ? baseColor : "#bdbebf"

        Text {
            text: "-"
            font.pixelSize: control.font.pixelSize * 2
            color: Qt.darker(baseColor, control.enabled ? 1 : 0.7)
            anchors.fill: parent
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 140
        border.color: "#bdbebf"
    }
}
```

May it can fit your needs.

Comment: Both variants don't work correctly in case editable = true